# Locate bower_components in laravel and using loadbalancer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I would like to know how can I call all my scripts file inside /public/bower_components in laravel? I'm having problem with the loading of all my scripts since we are also using a loadbalancer. Here's a sample of my code

URL: http://10.0.2.3/transaction/   <---- my project url where **10.0.2.3** is our loadbalancer/haproxy public IP and 'transaction' is the keyword use to reroute to our private server.

Now when I use this laravel script

```
{{ Html::script('bower_components/angular/angular.js') }}
```

I assumed that this will look for the angular.js file in the url

```
http://10.0.2.3/transaction/bower_components/angular/angular.js
```

but upon checking my file its looking in this url

```
http://10.0.2.3/bower_components/angular/angular.js
```

as you can see the keyword 'transaction' is removed. Is there a way to fix this so that it will look for the file in the correct path with 'transaction' included in the url?

Answer (score 0):

You can just write a custom helper to prepend the route

```
if(! function_exists('asset_lb') {
    function asset_lb($path) {
        return asset('/transaction/'.$path);  // <--- you need to customize the PATH Separator.
    }
}
```

then use in project

```
{{ asset_lb('bower_components/angular/angular.js') }}
```